# Bind grid row value to htmleditor

Tags: javascript, extjs, binding, extjs5

It is possible binding grid row value to an htmleditor?

Fiddle:https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17ev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `defaultBindProperty` is `html` in case of `htmleditor`, you'll need to use:

```
bind: { value: '{user.name}' }
```

instead of:

```
bind: '{user.name}'
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17f0